# nsis on Windows-7 reboot for .NET 4 installation does not continue installation

Tags: windows-7, nsis

When installing my application I also install the .NET 4.0 redistributable if .NET 4.0 is not present on the machine.

On Windows-7 this sometimes (maybe always) causes a reboot (outside of nsis's control).

I should like the installation to continue after the reboot.

I should be grateful for advice on how to address this scenario with nsis.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [RunOnce](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa376977(VS.85).aspx) registry key.

NSIS does not support the restart manager (But it is probably possible to call [RegisterApplicationRestart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa373347(v=VS.85).aspx) yourself with the system plugin).

Either way, the "restart command" probably needs to include a parameter you can detect so your installer does start from the beginning again (Use [GetParameters](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/AppendixE.html#E.1.11) and [PageJump](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Go_to_a_NSIS_page)).

Answer (score 2):

Call the .net installer with command line switch `/norestart`

Answer (score 0):

Using `/norestart` might not be an option for you if you are installing other software that requires .NET 4.0 to already be installed. In my case for example, I am installing .NET 3.5 on Windows XP, then installing SQL Server 2008 R2. The SQL Server 2008 installer requires .NET 3.5 to already be installed, so /norestart is not an option here -- if used, SQL Server 2008 won't install. Therefore, Anders' suggestion to use the RunOnce registry key is the solution I'll need to go with.